# Separate bibliography in arbitrary sections

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I use bibtex to manage my bibliography. My report concerns different subject, so I'd like to separate my bibliography in sections. One interested by only one subject could read only the section he is interested in.

I've read several Q&A, but the closest I've found is to automatically generate the section using either the kind of entry (article, manual, etc.) or the place of the reference in the report. Neither of those solutions corresponds to what I'm looking for. I'd like to manually insert the reference in the section I want.

Is the only solution to create separate bibliography or is there something simpler?

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I cited as what I don't want. ;) I don't want to sort my bibliography by type of refered items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tries and thanks to [this link](https://fr.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_management_with_biblatex), I've come to something that I like.

Here is a sample of `biblio.bib`:

```
@manual
{ref1,
keywords={keyword1},
title={Cool stuff},
[other stuff]
}

@manual
{ref2,
keywords={keyword2},
title={Other cool stuff},
[other stuff]
}
```

In the preamble of my report I have:

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=numeric,
sorting=none
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
```

And to add the bibliography (also in the summary):

```
\section*{Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliography}
\printbibliography[keyword={keyword1},title={Bibliography of keyword1}]
\printbibliography[keyword={keyword2},title={Bibliography of keyword2}]
```